# Oracle 10g - An invisible column?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to 'hide' a column in an Oracle 10g database, or prevent data from being inserted altogether? We'd prefer to have existing INSERT statements still function, but have the information NOT insert for a particular column. Also, column masking or any type of encryption is not preferred.

Not sure if it's possible, but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is stop data from being inserted, you could create a BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW trigger that wipes out any value inserted into the column before the row is saved.

There are various other things you can do with security (also views) to prevent inserts/selects from particular users in particular circumstances, but these will probably not let existing inserts continue to work.

Comment: This is most likely the route we would like to take... Do you know if the original INSERT event would be logged, or just the trigger event?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends what you mean by "logged"... As far as the transaction log goes, it should only be a single INSERT with the values as modified by the trigger (i.e., there wouldn't be two entries), but I suppose a lower-level audit log or something might record the original version somewhere...

Comment: Your question is about 10g, but know that 12c added explicit support for invisible columns. See for example http://blog.contractoracle.com/2013/06/oracle-12c-new-features-invisible.html. And SQL*Plus 12c has an option to show them still (so not quite invisible after all): http://tkyte.blogspot.fr/2013/07/12c-sql-plus-new-things.html.

Answer (score 2):

With Oracle feature virtual private database (VPD) you can define which users can change and which users can select a column. Virtual private database is also called fine-grained access control (FGAC).

Answer (score 2):

I know how to hide the column.

- You use the

  > SET UNUSED

  option to mark one or more columns as unused.
- You use the DROP

  > UNUSED COLUMNS

  option to remove the columns that are marked as unused.

> ALTER TABLE emp
>   SET UNUSED (last_name);

and

> ALTER TABLE emp
>   DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;

Answer (score 1):

Rename original table, create view with original table name but only selecting the columns you want to show.

Recompile code referring to existing table.

Answer (score 0):

what about just setting your grants to each item you allow to update or insert

```
grant select on emp to scott;

grant update (column1, column2), insert (column1) on emp to scott
```